# Promethius, group_left, and "on" vs "ignoring"

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

In [Issue #2204](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2204), one of the Prometheus developers says:

> ...in principle you should be favouring `ignoring` over `on` to produce generic shareable rules...

I'm confused how the use of `ignoring` would lead to more generic rules.  For example, consider a situation where we have one "info" metric for a device and several statistics, like this:

```
device_info{id="1", owner="coyote", project="acme"}
device_rx_bytes{id="1"}
device_tx_bytes{id="1"}
device_rx_errors{id="1"}
device_tx_errors{id="1"}
```

If I want to get the receive rate by project, I would need to correlate the `device_rx_bytes` metric with the corresponding `device_info` metric. To me this smells like a SQL join, and I would write:

```
rate(device_rx_bytes[5m]) * on(id) group_left(project) device_info
```

This seems "generic" in the sense that it only makes assumptions about the label used for the grouping (`id`) and the label we want to propagate to our results (`project`). If I understand the `ignoring` operator correctly, the corresponding expression would be more complex because I would need to list out all labels from the right-hand side that don't exist in the left-hand side. Something like:

```
rate(device_rx_bytes[5m]) * ignoring(owner, project) group_left(project) device_info
```

Is that correct? And if it is, why is `ignoring` preferred over `on` (not just in the quote above, but in various documentation and examples as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the keyword in that comment is `shareable` or in other words *reusable* rules. Meaning you (often) preserve more labels while using `ignoring` compared to `on` and the results will be (usually) a rule with more of it's original labels left intact, so it can be reused for more scenarios.

Imagine these time series:

```
instance_cpu_time_ns{app="lion", proc="web", rev="34d0f99", env="prod", job="cluster-manager"}
instance_cpu_time_ns{app="elephant", proc="worker", rev="34d0f99", env="prod", job="cluster-manager"}
instance_cpu_time_ns{app="turtle", proc="api", rev="4d3a513", env="prod", job="cluster-manager"}
instance_cpu_time_ns{app="fox", proc="widget", rev="4d3a513", env="prod", job="cluster-manager"}
...
```

A query with `ignoring(rev)` leaves out all the other labels in the result, compared with the same query with `on(app)`.

But the result of `on` and `ignoring` would be identical if you use them with mutually exclusive set of labels, like the example you are mentioning.